# WP Gutenberg - How to parse simple images?

Tags: block-editor, rest-api, parse, wp-parse-args

I have made a REST API endpoint to fetch a single blog.

As a payload item is content.

```
$post_data = array(
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'title' => $post->post_title,
        'content' => $post->post_content,
        .....
    );
```

Works, but images inside content are simple, without a responsive "way".

How to parse image blocks and prepare "pure" images like

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img src="img.../oauth-login.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-643"/></figure>
```

To:

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full">
<img alt="team image" loading="lazy" width="370" height="426" decoding="async" data-nimg="1" sizes="100vw" 
srcset="img....&amp;w=640&amp;q=75 640w, 
img....&amp;w=750&amp;q=75 750w, 
....&amp;w=828&amp;q=75 828w, 
....&amp;w=1080&amp;q=75 1080w, 
....&amp;w=1200&amp;q=75 1200w, 
....&amp;w=1920&amp;q=75 1920w, 
....&amp;w=2048&amp;q=75 2048w, 
....&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75 3840w" 
src=".......&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75">

</figure>
```

With default WP image sizes.

Comment: why not use the built-in endpoint to fetch a blog post?

Answer (score 1):

When you return `$post->post_content` you're returning the raw content from the database. Things like shortcodes, dynamic blocks and responsive image markup will not exist in the content. To prepare content for output you need to run it through the `the_content` filter:

```
'content' => apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ),
```

That being said, there is already [an endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#retrieve-a-post) for retrieving a single post, so you'd be better off just using that.